# Dudas con consultas preparadas select e insert con PDO

Tags: php, pdo

el código que coloco acá tiene como fin insertar un nuevo usuario en la base de datos pero antes de la inserción es necesario validar si el documento de identidad ó el correo ya han sido registrados para de esta manera si existen enviar un mensaje y retornar al formulario y si no existen esos dos datos pues agregar al nuevo usuario.

El código está desarrollado en un principio cuando hace la primera consulta (SELECT) en PDO ya que lo he modificado y en el insert lo he dejado tal cual como lo tenía en php de forma procedimental utilizando myslqi.

¿Cuál es mi duda? bueno en principio si el código en PDO para hacer la validación es correcto ya que estoy iniciando en PDO, y la segunda duda se basa en que si nos fíjamos en el insert en el campo nombre yo le concateno un campo apellido que solo existe como variable en el formulario para viajar por post más no existe como campo en la base de datos, esto con el fin de que ambas cadenas de texto se guarden en el campo nombre de la bd, igual hago con letras y documento, en base a eso no he podido encontrar ó ver un ejemplo de como se podría hacer esa misma concatenación de textos en una consulta preparada con PDO, por otra parte también tengo la duda de como se guardaría un campo fecha si con date ó con la función NOW() y si los valores cableados que paso se guardarían tal cual como lo estoy haciendo en una consulta preparada con PDO. Acá el código, gracias de antemano a quienes se tomen el tiempo de responder:

```
<?php 
$nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
$apellido=!empty($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : NULL;
$letra=!empty($_POST['letra']) ? $_POST['letra'] : NULL;
$documento=!empty($_POST['documento']) ? $_POST['documento'] : NULL;
$correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;
$clave=!empty($_POST['clave']) ? $_POST['clave'] : NULL;
$fecha = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
$estatus = 1;
$tipodocumento="$letra $documento";
$nuevaClave = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if($nombre && $apellido && $documento && $correo && $clave){
include "./conexion.php";

$sql= "select COUNT(*) from usuario where documento = :documento or correo = :correo";
$stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":documento",$documento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":correo",$correo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
    $url="../login.php?error=Este usuario ya está registrado";
                    
}else{
                
                
               $sql2 = ("insert into usuario
               (nombre,apellido,documento,correo,clave,estatus_usuario,fecha_registro,id_nivel_usuario,
                id_reputacion_vendedor,id_reputacion_comprador) values
                (:nombre, :apellido, :documento, :correo, :clave, :estatus_usuario, :fecha, :id_nivel_usuario, :id_reputacion_vendedor,:id_reputacion_comprador)");
                $stmt2=$conexion->prepare($sql2);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":apellido", $apellido,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":documento", $letra,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":correo", $correo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
               // $crypt=password_hash($clave);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":clave", $clave,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindValue(":estatus_usuario",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt2->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindValue(":id_nivel_usuario",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt2->bindValue(":id_reputacion_vendedor",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt2->bindValue(":id_reputacion_comprador",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
       
        $url="../index.php?success"; 
        }
    
    }

    header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120466/discussion-on-question-by-apalazon-dudas-con-consultas-preparadas-select-e-inser).